# Converting Array into Image (tif) in Python using Pillow

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert an `array` into a image (**tif**) for compression (it will be undone at the other end). However, I'm falling at the first hurdle...

I have the following:

```
pillow_image = Image.fromarray(image_data)
```

Which gives me this error:

> ```
>   File "/Users/workspace/test-app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py",
> ```
>
> line 2155, in fromarray
>           arr = obj.**array_interface**
>       AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`image_data` is a tuple of 4 numpy arrays, each (probably) of shape (H, W). You
need `image_data` to be a single array of shape (H, W, 4). Therefore, use [np.dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to combine the channels.

At least one of your arrays has dtype int32. But to use it as an 8-bit color channel, the arrays needs to be of dtype `uint8` (so that the maximum value is 255). You can convert the array to dtype `uint8` using `astype`. Hopefully your data does not contain values greater than 255. If it does, `astype('uint8')` will keep only the least significant bits (i.e. return the number modulo 256).

```
image_data = np.dstack(image_data).astype('uint8')
pillow_image = Image.fromarray(image_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a informative answer. It it as simple to cover it back again?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cover". If you mean how to split it into 4 separate arrays again, then you could use `arr = np.array(pillow_image)` and `r, g, b, a = arr[..., 0], arr[..., 1], arr[..., 2], arr[..., 3]`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean convert them back to 4 arrays again. I can see from the link you posted some good examples. Thanks